# Create two buttons without space in between them

Tags: html, css

I need two "flat" buttons, without space between them. It should look like this:
[image]

Page itself is in AngularJS. So far I've created this (just snippet):

HTML:

```
  <body ng-app="">
    <section layout="row" layout-align="center center">
      <button id="legal" ng-click="businessType=true" ng-model="businessType" ng-init="businessType = true">Legal Person</button>
      <button id="individual" ng-click="businessType=false">Individual</button>
    </section>

    <p>Area 1 - common data</p>
    <hr>

    <div ng-if="businessType == true">
      <p>Area 2 - legal person data</p>
    </div>

    <div ng-if="businessType == false">
      <p>Area 2 - individual data</p>
    </div>

    <hr>
    <p>Area 3 - common data</p>
    <hr>
  </body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
button#legal:focus {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}

button#individual:focus {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nenadbulatovic/7p47w1a9/8/)

which looks (initially and when option selected) like:

[image][image]

I've tried several options, with AngularJS Material button etc., but none produced desired effect, i.e. buttons which looks like example on mockup ('flat' like, no space).

Any help with this, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try these styles *(as you have to override some default styles)* and don't forget [**to remove whitespace**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-do-i-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements) between buttons *(here I simply made them close to each other)*. You can also consider the `autofocus` attribute to have the focus at the start.

```css
button {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

button#legal:focus,
button#individual:focus {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <button id="legal" autofocus >Legal Person</button><button id="individual">Individual</button>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks! One more question, how do I 'set' focus on 'Legal Person' as this is going to be preselected? Would you add that to your answer, please?

Comment: @NenadBulatovic added ;) simply use autofocus

Comment: Thanks, so simple, yet effective!

Answer (score 2):

It's 2018! Wrap them inside an element with `display: inline-flex` or `display: flex`.

```css
.button-container {
  display: inline-flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="button-container">
  <button type="button">Button1</button>
  <button type="button">Button2</button>
  <button type="button">Button3</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because buttons are by default `inline` elements which take space to align itself.

So use **flex** to the button row which will make the `button` flex item. Also remove the `outline` of the `button`

***Stack Snippet***

```css
button#legal:focus {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}

button#individual:focus {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}

section[layout="row"] {
  display: flex;
}

button {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<body ng-app="">
  <section layout="row" layout-align="center center">
    <button id="legal" ng-click="businessType=true" ng-model="businessType" ng-init="businessType = true">Legal Person</button>
    <button id="individual" ng-click="businessType=false">Individual</button>
  </section>

  <p>Area 1 - common data</p>
  <hr>

  <div ng-if="businessType == true">
    <p>Area 2 - legal person data</p>
  </div>

  <div ng-if="businessType == false">
    <p>Area 2 - individual data</p>
  </div>

  <hr>
  <p>Area 3 - common data</p>
  <hr>
</body>
```

Comment: i think we should at least mention that he is facing whitespace issue which can be fixed with flex